# Why do I have to click twice on selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The following code makes me click twice to navigate to the page I need. But the problem is that I only want to select the option once, and as soon as I make my selection I want to navigate to the page I need. I see that no option is selected. I have to either press enter or click again on the option.

On change doesn't give me a keycode, that I need to use later on, if the user is blind and cannot use the mouse, he/she has to navigate only using the tab key. Onchange will trigger an immediate event, without letting the user chose and option. That is the reason why I cannot use OnChange since it's not consistent for visually impaired users on IE11

```js
  $(document).on("click", '.js-jump-to-page', function(e) {
      var url = $(this).val();
      var target = '_blank';
      if (url) {
        alert(url);
        window.open(url, target);
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-rates-jump-to-page-1" class="select js-jump-to-page">       
  <option tabindex="0" value="">Select a product</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.google.com">Bla Bla 1</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.yahoo.com">Bla Bla 2</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.bing.com">Bla Bla 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use change not click

Comment: Does using `keypress` work then? - I mean, the user makes a selection from the `select` menu and then how do we know the selection is the final? the user presses the `enter` key and we navigate away to the selected page/url?

Comment: @ochi aria labels are used with a screenreader to let know the user it's options and selections. But I cannot make it to work for a regular user. If you see my example. Isn't it weird that you have to click again on the option that was once previously selected?

Comment: I think I understand that part, I just do not understand how to determine that an option selected in the `select` box is the final one.  What would be the process like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `keypress` event might work here.

Once the user has selected an option, the user can press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key and we navigate away to the selected page/url

Kind of like this

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keypress", '.js-jump-to-page', function(e) {
    // check if the keypress is 'Enter'
    if (e.which === 13) {
      // get value of selected
      var selectedUrl = $(".js-jump-to-page").val();

      if (selectedUrl) {
        // now go to that page
        var target = '_blank';

        //close dropdown (not sure this works like this)
        $(".js-jump-to-page").blur();

        console.log('Going to: ' + selectedUrl);
        window.open(selectedUrl, target);
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", '.js-jump-to-page', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).val();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('selected: ' + url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-rates-jump-to-page-1" class="select js-jump-to-page">       
  <option tabindex="0" value="">Select a product</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.google.com">google</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.bing.com">bing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, unfortunately I keep having a problem on IE11 with the tab key. When I reach the dropdown with the tab key, the first selection it makes is the first option. So again, the user doesn't get the option to chose with the up and down arrows, because as soon as the option is reached it triggers the first option as selected without even hitting enter.

Comment: Can the first option be removed? maybe replaced with an aria label or other descriptor? is IE11 a must have requirement? and is that the only browser with the issue?

Comment: your solution worked perfectly actually, I just changed the second eventlistener to "click" instead of "change" Is there a reason why the keypress is first?

Comment: No reason, the order is not important in this case. I'll update my answer then

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of the `click` event.

```js
  $(document).on("change", '.js-jump-to-page', function(e) {
      var url = $(this).val();
      var target = '_blank';
      if (url) {
        alert(url);
        window.open(url, target);
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-rates-jump-to-page-1" class="select js-jump-to-page">       
  <option tabindex="0" value="">Select a product</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.google.com">Bla Bla 1</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.yahoo.com">Bla Bla 2</option>
  <option tabindex="0" value="www.bing.com">Bla Bla 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use select on change event

```
$( ".select" ).on('change', function() {
  var url = $(this).val();
  var target = '_blank';
  if (url) {
    alert(url);
    window.open(url, target);
  }
});
```

Comment: Because I am working on IT accessibility, and unfortunately using change will not work well with keypress

Comment: @Monica can you expand on your comment? The `.on('change'...)` event should be what you are looking for, I am not sure I understand how the `keypress` gets in the way...

Comment: @ochi Yes, On change doesn't give me a keycode, that I need to use later on, if the user is blind and cannot use the mouse, he/she has to navigate only using the tab key. Onchange will trigger an immediate event, without letting the user chose and option. https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/it-accessibility-at-nc-state/developers/accessibility-handbook/mouse-and-keyboard-events/

Comment: @Monica - I see.  You should add that requirement to the question then. It is not obvious that the limiting factor to your question is an accessibility one.  This is likely why people responded with using 'onChange' as the solution.

Comment: @ochi Thanks. I already edited the description of the problem